# iPhone - Trying to Copy sqlite Database to Documents Directory - copies blank version

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, database, sqlite

I have an sqlite database called 'ProductDatabase.sql', which I have copied into my applications project directory:

/Users/jacknutkins/Documents/TabbedDietApp/TabbedDietApp/ProductDatabase.sql

In the applications app delegate class I have this piece of code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    //Set-up some globals
    m_DatabaseName = @"ProductDatabase.sql";

    //Get the path to the documents directory and append the databaseName
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    m_DatabasePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ProductDatabase.sql"];

    //Execute the "checkAndCreateDatabase" function
    [self checkAndCreateDatabase];

    //Query the databse for all animal records and construct the "animals" array
    [self readProductsFromDatabase];

....
```

At this point:

m_DatabasePath = '/Users/jacknutkins/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/6D5BBE3A-BC9A-4C44-B089-FABA27CFFF4B/Library/ProductDatabase.sql'

Here is the code for the other 2 methods:

```
- (void) checkAndCreateDatabase {
    NSError * error;

    //Check if the database has been saved to the users phone, if not then copy it over
    BOOL l_Success;

    //Create a file manager object, we will use this to check the status
    //of the databse and to copy it over if required
    NSFileManager *l_FileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    //Check if the database has already been created in the users filesystem
    l_Success = [l_FileManager fileExistsAtPath:m_DatabasePath];

    //If the database already exists then return without doing anything

    if(l_Success)
        return;

    //If not then proceed to copy the database from the application to the users filesystem

    //Get the path to the database in the application package
    NSString *l_DatabasePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:m_DatabaseName];

    //Copy the database from the package to the usrrs filesystem
    [l_FileManager copyItemAtPath:l_DatabasePathFromApp toPath:m_DatabasePath error:&error];

}
```

If I perform some NSLogs here:

**l_DatabasePathFromApp** = /Users/jacknutkins/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/6D5BBE3A-BC9A-4C44-B089-FABA27CFFF4B/TabbedDietApp.app/ProductDatabase.sql

and:

**error** = Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 260.)" UserInfo=0x6b6d060 {NSFilePath=/Users/jacknutkins/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/6D5BBE3A-BC9A-4C44-B089-FABA27CFFF4B/TabbedDietApp.app/ProductDatabase.sql, NSUnderlyingError=0x6b6cfa0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory"}

I'm not sure what file it is it can't find here..

```
- (void) readProductsFromDatabase {
    //Init the products array
    m_Products = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"%@", m_DatabasePath);
    //Open the database from the users filessystem
    if(sqlite3_open([m_DatabasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
        //Set-up the SQL statement and compile it for faster access
        const char *sqlStatement = "select * from products";
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSLog(@"Success..");
            //Loop through the results and add them to the feeds array
            while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                //Read the data from the results row
                NSString *aName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];
                NSString *aCategory = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];
                NSString *aCalories = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 3)];
                NSString *aFat = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 4)];
                NSString *aSaturates = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 5)];
                NSString *aSugar = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 6)];
                NSString *aFibre = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 7)];
                NSString *aSalt = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 8)];
                NSString *aImageURL = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 9)];
                NSLog(@"Delegate");
                NSString *aNote = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 10)];
                NSUInteger myInt = sqlite3_column_int(compiledStatement, 11);
                NSString *aServes = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", myInt];

                //Create a new animal object with the data from the database
                Product *l_Product = [[Product alloc] initWithName:aName category:aCategory calories:aCalories fat:aFat saturates:aSaturates sugar:aSugar fibre:aFibre salt:aSalt imageURL:aImageURL note:aNote serves:aServes];

                //Add the animal object to the animals array
                [m_Products addObject:l_Product];

            }
        }
        //Release the compiled statement from memory
        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);

    }
    sqlite3_close(database);

}
```

database is declared in the .h file as follows:

```
//Setup the database object
    sqlite3 *database;
```

In the above method, the line:

```
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
```

does not evaluate to SQLITE_OK, because the database I try to copy to the documents directory is blank.

I have tried cleaning and building, deleting the blank copy of the database and re-running etc but it continues to copy a blank database every time.

I've googled this several times and I've tried everything I can find with no success..

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Jack

**EDIT**

If I perform 'select * from products' from the terminal window on the database in the project directory I return the expected results.

Comment: Yes, I use ARC.  And yes m_DatabasePath is a property, hadn't tried with self.m_DatabasePath but I just did and it didn't change anything.

Comment: If you click on the database file on the left side of the Xcode window, make sure that the Utilities view is open on the right side of the Xcode window, and then click on the File Inspector tab icon (the small piece of paper), is the database file's target membership checked?

Comment: Christ, 2 days I've spent on this, 2 days... thanks @BP.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had forgotten to include the database file in the target membership by clicking on the check box in the file inspector tab.